# Update scope name into directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which attribute contains a scope name that I would like to update when something has been set in the directive.

```
<div data-my-directive data-scope-var-to-update="my_scope_variable"></div>



.directive('myDirective', function($rootScope){
        return function(scope, element, attrs){

            var scope_var_name = attrs.scopeVarToUpdate;

            scope[scope_var_name] = 'This message was updated from the directive';
        }
    })
```

The above allows me to do what I want only if the scope variable does not contain any dot notations.

My question is how can modify the above to cater for scope variables that contain dot notations for example $scope.a.b?

```
<div data-my-directive data-scope-var-to-update="a.b"></div>
```

The idea behind the above is to pass in any scope variable name and update it from the directive once its done it's job which means the new assignment should be accessible by the parent controller.

Comment: I think you'd have to parse the string and create each object individually.  Like a={} then a.b = "This message was update....".

Comment: @CraigSquire fortunately angular has a function for it, `scope.$eval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $parse service for dot notation model. Something like this in your directive

```
var getter = $parse(parseattrs.scopeVarToUpdate);
var setter = getter.assign;
getter(scope);   //get value
setter(scope,'value'); //set value
```

See documentation for this here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse

Comment: I like this answer, I had to try it out for myself because I haven't used the parse service before.  http://plnkr.co/edit/BaKc7GEt5zXnnhQxJHBk

Answer (score 1):

You use `scope.$eval(attrs.scopeVarToUpdate)`

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$eval(attrs.scopeVarToUpdate) = 'This message was updated from the directive';
    }
})
```

Or use an isolated scope with two-way binding and don't worry about any of that.
Isolated scope version:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
      scope:{scopeVarToUpdate:'='},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.scopeVarToUpdate = 'This message was updated from the directive';
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: For the first option I'm getting:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Ahh, try `var model  = scope.$eval(attrs.scopeVarToUpdate); model = 'whatever';`